# Swift3 - UIImageView isn't appearing from parsed JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift3, jsonparser

Hey guys would love some help with my first question. I've spent ages going through the forum but am still struggling to understand where I'm going wrong with this. The URL string is parsing fine from the JSON, however it is not displaying as an image in the UIImageView I have created. The code is compiling fine and everything else is displaying. I'm assuming I have to convert the URL which is type String to a UIImageView however I keep getting errors.

Here is the snippet of the EventCell class.

```
class EventCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var event: Event?   {
    didSet  {

        if let eventName = event?.title {
            eventTitle.text = eventName
        }

        eventSubtitle.text = event?.subtitle

        eventTags.text = event?.tags

        if let imageName = event?.imageURL
        {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect)    {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


let imageView: UIImageView =  {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()
```

And here is the snippet of the Event class itself.

```
var id: NSNumber?
var title: String?
var imageURL: String?
var subtitle: String?
var tags: String?
var desc: String?

override init(){}

init(event: NSDictionary)
{
    if let val = event["ID"] as? NSNumber
    {
        id = val;
    }

    if let val = event["Title"] as? String
    {
        title = val;
    }

    if let val = event["Subtitle"] as? String
    {
        subtitle = val;
    }

    if let val = event["Tags"] as? String
    {
        tags = val;
    }

    if let val = event["Description"] as? String
    {
        desc = val;
    }

    if let val = event["image"] as? String
    {
        imageURL = val;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you can't just initialize `UIImage` from a URL string. you need to download the image data then initializing from data.

Comment: Make sure you have a file named imageName. You cannot use external link to create image.

Comment: update question with `error` that was you got. Also update code snippet where you get `error`

Comment: You need first download the image with this url I suggest use SDWebImage library to help you with that and then set the UIImageView.image = yourDownloadedImage

Comment: Not related but as all properties in `Event` are optional anyway why do you optional bind each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this extension

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no errror")
                }
                else {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
imageView.imageFromUrl(urlString: "http://linktoyourimage.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

The initialiser `UIImage(named:)` expects the name of an image that is already stored in the bundle. In your case, you want to load an image from a `URL`. What you should do is create a `URL` from the `String`, then load the contents of that `URL` as `NSData` and finally create a `UIImage` from that `Data`. The quickest way to achieve this is

```
if let imageURLString = event?.imageURL {
    let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString!)
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL!)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
}
```

**NOTE**

A few points to take into consideration

- This is not the best approach to load an image from a `URL`. You should also look into `async` requests. However, this is the quickest implementation and should get the code working
- The snippet is in `Swift 3` syntax. I'm assuming you can convert it to `Swift 2` if that's what you are using

Comment: Thanks so much Malik! Code now runs and images compile. But yes you are correct. App is extremely sluggish and almost unusable. Would you also recommend loading images from a seperate thread?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes it is better to load it in a seperate thread. Look into Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple documentation `UIImage(named:)` expects name of the name in your app bundle. You can pass the url of your image in `dataWithContentsOfURL:` method. Though using this approach is fine, you just need to process asynchronously as approach with dataWithContentsOfURL: is a synchronous request and blocks the main thread until that download is complete.

Consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) an UIImageView extension, it adds to manage the image download and display. It also supports a placeholder image that you can supply to indicate that the download is in progress.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks heaps luckyShubra. And yes I can see now having implemented the fix that this requests makes the app unusable so will have to have a look into this extension. Thanks again.

Comment: M glad your u could resolve your issue. SDWebImage is easy to use UIImageView extension. Check details in the link above.